# Are rituals for worshipping shivlinga necessary to please Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, worship, parvati

Lord Shiva is known as Ashutosh ,meaning easily pleased but there are many rituals for worshipping a shivlinga like use milk to bathe the lingam, not to consume the fruits offered to him as Prasad,  always keep the lingam under continuous water flow ,sprinkle gangajal over yourself before puja ,don't use kumkum or turmeric or ketaki flower etc.Are these necessary to please him or these are just manmade ?

Comment: AshuTosha does not mean you just say Hi to Shiva and He will be pleased with a smile on His face. Yes Maheshvara is AashuToshi, quickly satisfied, but the rituals of offering milk, fruits, water , not offering Ketaki and turmeric et cetera hold great importance.

Comment: An important question. Rituals matter only as long as love is not there. The analogy is one uses a fan as long as there is no breeze blowing. Once love dawns then these rituals are not necessary. When a storm comes one does not need a fan.

Answer (score 6):

These rules are mentioned in some scriptures (i.e the ShAstras) or the other. So, you can take them as the orders of God himself..

Now, it's upto you to decide, whether by not following the orders of God you can please him or by following them..

For example, that Ketaki flower should not used in Shiva Puja, is something mentioned in the Devi BhAgavata PurAna:

> Never worship Visnu with rice; Ganes’a with Tulasî leaves; the Devî
>   Durgâ with Durba grass and **S’iva with Ketakî flower**.
>
> **From the PurAna's Book 11, Chapter 17.**

So, these rules are certainly not man made. And you can now decide what to do with them.